# Projective dimension and tensorial product of two modules

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $M$,$N$ be two modules over commutative ring $R$.
Can we say that $pd (M \otimes N )= $ $pd( M) + pd( N)$?
Thanks!

Comment: No: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $N=\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: No. For instance take for $R$ a domain, and $M=N=R/(x)$, for some $x\neq 0$. Then $\mathrm{pd}(M\otimes _RN)=\mathrm{pd}(M)=\mathrm{pd}(N)=1$.

Comment: thank you! So do we have some inequality between this two invariant?

Comment: I don't think so. In the above examples we have $\mathrm{pd}(M\otimes_R N)<\mathrm{pd}(M)+\mathrm{pd}(N)$, but there are examples where $\mathrm{pd}(M\otimes_R N)$ is infinite: take $R=k[[x,y]]/(x^2-y^3)$, $M=R/(x)$, $N=R/(y)$. Then $M\otimes _RN$ is the residual field, which has infinite projective dimension because $R$ is not regular.

Comment: And if we assume that $gldim(R)$ is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ and $N$ are Tor-independent (i.e., Tor$_i^R(M,N)=0$ for $i>0$), then you have some positive results. For instance if $R$ is local complete intersection, the three modules are of finite projective dimension (and finite) then you have an affirmative answer as a consequence of Auslander-Buchschaum formula and Hunecke-Wiegand depth formula. See e.g. the expository paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.2170.pdf mainly section 6. This answers less than the above comments, but I cannot comment due to reputation.

Comment: I wanted to add to your answer that, in the Tor independent case, you get $\leq$ without further conditions since the tensor product of projective resolutions is a projective resolution of the tensor product.